# Adding a JS DOM element to an empty html shell

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create nodes in JS and add them to an empty html file (Just the shell, not *actually* empty and when trying to append the div to the body, I get this error:

HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
    at test

```
function test() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var para = document.createElement("p")
  var node = document.createTextNode("Hello");
  para.appendChild(node);
  div.appendChild(para);
  document.body.appendChild(para);
}
test();
```

The last statement is giving me the error, is that statement not the correct way to append?

Comment: It's [working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/u82d3sxm/) for me. Voting to close as non-reproduceable.